# Meaning of "Tertiary level" In New Zealand programmer job listings

Tags: terminology, definitions

What does the phrase "Be qualified at the Tertiary level" mean in the context of a New Zealand listing for programming jobs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tertiary in New Zealand can be University or Polytechnic education. In other words, any formal education after Secondary School, which in New Zealand is the 5 years from age 12-14 to 17-19.

Qualifications would include a degree or diploma. So basically, your non New Zealand qualification has to fit the above definition to fit the job description.

As someone who hired software engineers from overseas, I would be happy to hear what qualification you have got and give a non-official assessment of whether it would qualify under the above criterion.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps they mean [tertiary education](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_education)?

Answer (score 2):

It quite definitely means tertiary (i.e. university level) education.

Are you familiar with the terms Primary School (roughly like "grade school"), and Secondary School (i.e. High School)? What comes after primary and secondary? - yep, tertiary